# How to solve the numba type error led in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend) Invalid use of type(CPUDispatcher(<function

Tags: python, numpy, numba

So I am trying to  write a code with numba that is calculating eigenvalues of a complex matrix and gives eigenvalues which are complex but with infinitesimally small imaginary part which is expected. then it defines functions  by using those eigen values,

the code is as follows

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la
from numpy.linalg import eig
from scipy import integrate, LowLevelCallable
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from numba import cfunc, jit
from numba.types import intc, CPointer, float64, complex128
t0 = 2.61
t4 = 0.138
t3 = 0.283
t1 = 0.361
Delta = 0.015
d = 3.5
a = 2.46
D = 50e-3
mu = -0.02487
B = 0
theta = 0
omp = 1e-8
T = 0.9

@jit(complex128(intc,intc,intc,intc)) 
def  E(n, tau, k_x, k_y):
    v = t0*a*np.sqrt(3)/2
    v4 = t4*a*np.sqrt(3)/2
    v3 = t3*a*np.sqrt(3)/2
    
    p = tau*k_x + 1j*k_y
    p1 = tau*(k_x + B*d/2*np.sin(theta)) + 1j*(k_y - B*d/2*np.cos(theta))
    p2 = tau*(k_x - B*d/2*np.sin(theta)) - 1j*(k_y - B*d/2*np.cos(theta))
    
    H = np.array([[D/2-mu, v*np.conj(p1), -v4*np.conj(p), -v3*p],
                  [v*p1, Delta + D/2 - mu, t1, -v4*np.conj(p)],
                  [-v4*p, t1, Delta - D/2 - mu, v*np.conj(p2)],
                  [-v3*np.conj(p), -v4*p, v*p2, -D/2 - mu]])
    eigenvals, eigenvecs = eig(H)
  
 
    # Energies
    n = int(np.real(n))
    E = eigenvals[n] 
    return np.real(E)
@jit(complex128(intc,intc,intc,intc))  
def nf(n, tau, k_x, k_y):
    return 1.0 / (1. + np.exp(-2. * (mu - E(n, tau, k_x, k_y)) / T))
@jit(complex128(intc,intc,intc,intc,intc,intc,intc)) 
def I2(k_x, k_y, q_x, q_y, n_temp, m_temp, tau_temp):
    numerator = nf(n_temp, tau_temp, q_x, q_y) - nf(m_temp, tau_temp, q_x + k_x, q_y + k_y)
    denominator = omp + E(n_temp, tau_temp, q_x, q_y) - E(m_temp, tau_temp, q_x + k_x, q_y + k_y)
    return numerator / denominator
@jit(complex128(intc,intc,intc,intc,intc,intc,intc))
def fun(k_x,k_y,q_x,q_y,n_temp,m_temp,tau_temp): 
    return I2(k_x,k_y,q_x,q_y,n_temp,m_temp,tau_temp)

@jit(complex128(intc,intc,intc,intc,intc,intc,intc))
def funpp(k_x,k_y,q_x,q_y,n_temp,m_temp,tau_temp):
    return fun(k_x,k_y,q_x,q_y,n_temp,m_temp,tau_temp)/(2.*np.pi)**2.


def jit_integrand_function(integrand_function):
    jitted_function = jit(integrand_function, nopython=True)

    @cfunc(complex128(intc, CPointer(complex128)))
    def wrapped(n, xx):
        return jitted_function(xx[0], xx[1], xx[2], xx[3], xx[4], xx[5], xx[6])
    return LowLevelCallable(wrapped.ctypes)
#@cfunc(float64(intc, CPointer(float64)))
@jit_integrand_function
def funppr(k_x,k_y,q_r,q_t,n_temp,m_temp,tau_temp):
    return funpp(k_x,k_y,q_r*np.cos(q_t),q_r*np.sin(q_t),n_temp,m_temp,tau_temp)*q_r
```

when I run this I get

```
runfile('C:/Users/o/.spyder-py3/untitled3.py', wdir='C:/Users/oturker/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\o\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "c:\users\o\.spyder-py3\untitled3.py", line 83, in <module>
    def funppr(k_x,k_y,q_r,q_t,n_temp,m_temp,tau_temp):

  File "c:\users\o\.spyder-py3\untitled3.py", line 78, in jit_integrand_function
    def wrapped(n, xx):

  File "C:\Users\o\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\decorators.py", line 282, in wrapper
    res.compile()

  File "C:\Users\o\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_lock.py", line 35, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\o\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\ccallback.py", line 67, in compile
    cres = self._compile_uncached()

  File "C:\Users\o\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\ccallback.py", line 81, in _compile_uncached
    return self._compiler.compile(sig.args, sig.return_type)

  File "C:\Users\o\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 129, in compile
    raise retval

  File "C:\Users\o\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 139, in _compile_cached
    retval = self._compile_core(args, return_type)

  File "C:\Users\o\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 152, in _compile_core
    cres = compiler.compile_extra(self.targetdescr.typing_context,

  File "C:\Users\o\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler.py", line 693, in compile_extra
    return pipeline.compile_extra(func)

  File "C:\Users\o\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler.py", line 429, in compile_extra
    return self._compile_bytecode()

  File "C:\Users\o\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler.py", line 497, in _compile_bytecode
    return self._compile_core()

  File "C:\Users\o\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler.py", line 476, in _compile_core
    raise e

  File "C:\Users\o\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler.py", line 463, in _compile_core
    pm.run(self.state)

  File "C:\Users\o\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_machinery.py", line 353, in run
    raise patched_exception

  File "C:\Users\o\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_machinery.py", line 341, in run
    self._runPass(idx, pass_inst, state)

  File "C:\Users\o\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_lock.py", line 35, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\o\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_machinery.py", line 296, in _runPass
    mutated |= check(pss.run_pass, internal_state)

  File "C:\Users\o\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_machinery.py", line 269, in check
    mangled = func(compiler_state)

  File "C:\Users\o\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\typed_passes.py", line 105, in run_pass
    typemap, return_type, calltypes, errs = type_inference_stage(

  File "C:\Users\o\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\typed_passes.py", line 83, in type_inference_stage
    errs = infer.propagate(raise_errors=raise_errors)

  File "C:\Users\o\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\typeinfer.py", line 1086, in propagate
    raise errors[0]

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Invalid use of type(CPUDispatcher(<function funpp at 0x00000224F33CB280>)) with parameters (complex128, complex128, complex128, complex128, complex128, complex128, complex128)
Known signatures:
 * (int32, int32, int32, int32, int32, int32, int32) -> complex128
During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function funpp at 0x00000224F33CB280>))
During: typing of call at c:\users\o\.spyder-py3\untitled3.py (84)


File "untitled3.py", line 84:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>

During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function funppr at 0x00000224F3CDA700>))
During: typing of call at c:\users\o\.spyder-py3\untitled3.py (79)

During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function funppr at 0x00000224F3CDA700>))
During: typing of call at c:\users\o\.spyder-py3\untitled3.py (79)
```

When I run this and then try to evaluate the functions I have defined up to
`jit_integrand_function`
they work.